# remove scraped data with an empty value

Tags: python, scrapy

Suppose I am scraping data and some of the fields scraped `""`, meaning no value.

I don't want a row with `""` in it. How can I do it?
example:

```
field1       field2     field3
my place     blurred    trying
house        fan               
door         mouse      hat
```

What I want is for my program not to write the entire 2nd row to the CSV because the field3 is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write and configure an Item Pipeline following instructions from [the scrapy docs] and drop item with a test on it's values.

Add this in your `pipeline.py` file:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class DropIfEmptyFieldPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        # to test if only "job_id" is empty,
        # change to:
        # if not(item["job_id"]):
        if not(all(item.values())):
            raise DropItem()
        else:
            return item
```

And set this in your `settings.py` (adapt to your projet's name)

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = [ 'myproject.pipeline.DropIfEmptyFieldPipeline', ]
```

---

Edit after OP's comment about testing for "Nurse"

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
import re

class DropIfEmptyFieldPipeline(object):

    # case-insensitive search for string "nurse"
    REGEX_NURSE = re.compile(r'nurse', re.IGNORECASE)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # user .search() and not .match() to test for substring match
        if not(self.REGEX_NURSE.search(item["job_id"])):
            raise DropItem()
        else:
            return item
```

Comment: Yes, and don't forget to enable it through `ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'myproject.pipeline.DropIfEmptyFieldPipeline',
]` (change `myproject` of course) in your `settings.py`

Comment: this is my code in the
item ["job_id"] = id.select('text()').extract()[0].strip()
and it sometimes results to an empty field...
what should be put in the pipeline so that the entire row is not saved in the csv

Comment: I can see that this works if any field is empty. But what if I want only item ["job_id"] to be my indicator(if empty or not) so that the entire row is dropped!

Comment: Change from `if not(all(item.values())):` to `if not(item["job_id"]):`

Comment: What if I want my job_id to detect "Nurse" and if not detected, it is dropped?

Comment: exceptions.TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: do you have a list in item['job_id']? use `if not(self.REGEX_NURSE.search(item["job_id"][0])):`

Comment: great! It now it worked... I used it as elif because I used if not(all(item.values())): for tracking any empty fields

Comment: some of the files are ok and some still gets the error index out of range

Comment: Try `if item["job_id"] or not(self.REGEX_NURSE.search(item["job_id"][0])):`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36524/discussion-between-paul-t-and-chano)

Comment: Oops, should have been `if not item["job_id"] or not(self.REGEX_NURSE.search(item["job_id"][0])):`, meaning "if item["job_id"] is None or an empty list or ...